# matrix (square) is symmetric about the main diagonal

Tags: prolog

Define a predicate that determines whether a matrix (square) is symmetric about the main diagonal. The predicate would read about, where Z is a matrix (square) symmetric about the main diagonal

symmetrical (Z)

The idea is to check that the rows and columns are equal, but do not know how to begin to raise the exercise ...

Comment: You should start by defining the structure to hold the matrix (it could be as simple as a list of lists or something more complex), then check whether M[i][j]=M[j][i] for every i,j...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good old matrix I,J indexing:

```
symmetrical(M) :-
   forall(elem(M, I, J, E), elem(M, J, I, E)).

elem(M, I, J, E) :-
   nth1(I, M, R),
   nth1(J, R, E).
```

test:

```
?- symmetrical([[a,b],[b,a]]).
true.

?- symmetrical([[a,b],[a,b]]).
false.
```

*note* I wrote this before I saw @gusbro comment, but it's exactly what he suggested...

Comment: Your version is only testing. Try `synmetrical([[A,B],[C,D]]).` which should give `A = D, B = C`.

Answer (score 3):

```
symmetrical(Z) :-
   transpose(Z,Z).
```

Now, you only need to define transpose!

Comment: @gusbro: Where do you read it from that OP knows this? I cannot see anything.

Comment: where he states he needs to check whether "Z is a matrix (square) symmetric about the main diagonal".

Comment: great answer, with CLP(FD) `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).`

Comment: transpose/2 is autoloaded from lists? Then it's changed recently...I can't get to work without `:-[library(clpfd)].`

Comment: @chac: ah, I get it. Yes, your are right, but it uses `must_be/2` no need for that!